# Creating a custom object in PHP, that is sent to a SOAP service

Tags: php, oop, soap

I am trying to build up a customer object in PHP and then send to a asmx web service. Everything works fine except that I build an array inside the PHP. When I send it to the web-service only the last order history appears.

Here is the contract specified by the web service. Note this is pizza-code and not the actual code as the contract contain sensitive data.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set;}
    public int Name { get; set;}
    public int Surname { get; set;}
    public OrderHistory History { get; set;}
}

public class OrderHistory
{
     public int NumberOfOrders { get;set;}
     public Orders[] Orders { get;set;}
}

public class Orders
{
     public int OrderId { get;set;}
     public decimal Total {get;set;}
}
```

Here is how I build up the PHP object.

```
$params_create_save = array("Customer" => 
    array("CustomerId" => "111",
          "Name" => "Joe",
          "Surname" => "Soap",
          "History" => array("NumberOfOrders" => "10",
                              "Orders" => array("OrdersId" => "1"
                                                "Total" => "500.00"),
                              "Orders" => array("OrderId" => "1",
                                                "Total" => "200.00"),
                             ),
                        ),
                 ),
            ),
      ),
```

Questions:

1. Does the above PHP look correct? Am I missing something?
2. Can I create a seperate Order History object and just assign it to the parent. If yes please can you provide me with a small sample code?
3. Is there other ways I can build this object?

Thanks for taking the time to look at this! 
-E-

Comment: The way you create classes in PHP is wrong. You should read up on OOP with PHP. Those classes have a lot of errors.

Comment: When you said object, I was thinking an instance of StdClass. Kinda confusing, since you're building an array

Comment: I am a c# dev so I apologize if my terminology might be incorrect,. Would it be possible you to maybe provide me on how to create a class in PHP containing an array. It doesn't need to conform to the contract above.